# Tensorflow: LSTM and Convolution on subset of dimensions (avoiding unstack?)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm implementing a pretty standard LSTM model for NLP, where I initialize each word with pretrained embeddings.  For each word vector, I'd like to concatenate a LSTM encoding of the character sequence (for that word) and a convolutional encoding of the character sequence (for that word).

My input tensor has the shape: [batch size, max word sequence length, max char sequence length, char alphabet size]. If I unpack along dimension 0, I get tensors of shape [max word sequence length, max char sequence length, alphabet size], which I can easily run LSTM/ 1D-Convolution on.  However, this significantly slows down graph creation and the model training seems significantly slower also.

Here's the code for the LSTM encoding:

```
chars = tf.unstack(chars, axis=0)
lengths = tf.unstack(lengths, axis=0)

lstm_word_embeddings = []
for i, (char, length) in enumerate(zip(chars, lengths)):
    reuse = i != 0
    embedding = lstm_encoder(char, length, embed_dim, scope=scope, reuse=reuse)
    lstm_word_embeddings.append(embedding)
lstm_word_embeddings = tf.stack(lstm_word_embeddings, axis=0)
```

Is there a better way to do this?